# Should break/continue/return be interrupted by an exception?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

I came upon an interesting scenario with flow control while working on my language. What happens if an exception is thrown while processing a `break` statement. GCC seems to believe the break flow is lost, but the standard seems somewhat silent on what should happen.

For example, what should the following program actually do?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct maybe_fail {
    bool fail;
    ~maybe_fail() {
        if( fail )
            throw 1;
    }
};

int main() {
    for( int i=0; i < 6; ++i ) {
        cout << "Loop: " << i << endl;

        try {
            maybe_fail mf;
            mf.fail = i % 2;
            if( i == 3 )
                break;

        } catch( int ) {
            cout << "Caught" << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note that a `return` will also be blocked, as will a `continue` (add output after the catch to see that). Attempt to `goto` outside of the block will also be caught.

What is the correct flow? The standard doesn't seem to address this: section 6.6 on jump statements makes no mention, neither does section 15 on exception handling. I do understand that exceptions in destructors is in terribly bad form, but if you are using something like BOOST_SCOPE_EXIT for defer statements this behaviour might become quite important.

*Perhaps of interest, the same flow happens in Java and Python, so at least there seems to be some consistency in the imperative languages.*

Comment: Your question seems to vindicate the advice in the C++ FAQ: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/dtors-shouldnt-throw.html  Basically, don't throw exceptions in destructors.  This question in the FAQ was saying how `terminate()` is called if you're in a "double-exception-handling" situation, but your example seems to continue the advice that it's just bad to do so.

Comment: @Kevin, absolutely, that advice would then extend to any "defer" like statement in any language (including BOOST_SCOPE_EXIT for C++).

Comment: how else would you interpret the behavior? throw the exception in the destructor, and then what?

Comment: @bdwain, the end of the throw statement could continue with the `break` statement and exit the loop (exiting the loop __is__ what is intended when somebody writes `break` so it makes an equal amount of sense, if not more)

Comment: it is what they indended but the break statement finishes before the exception is thrown. If there was no exception, the of control would continue like break intended. But since there is, that flow is interrupted and never returned because of the exception. The break statement itself isn't interrupted though. Just the flow it set in motion. It just jumped to the end of the block, which started the sequence of destructors.

Comment: @bdwain, the break doesn't end with the immediate scope, the break flow needs to break out of the entire loop. Thus the exception is right in the middle of the break flow, not before, and not after.

Comment: @Kevin Still this doesn't change anything in the fact that the behaviour should be specified by the standard in some way. Non-throwing destructors are a suggestion but in no way a prohibition. It's not that throwing destructors are UB or something, their behaviour is perfectly defined (except maybe for the case of this question, though even if that would be UB, the standard should say so).

Comment: how does the standard say to handle a break like that, where you break out of 2 scopes, and the inner one has a destructor. Forgetting about throwing the exception for a second.

Comment: @bdwain When you think about it, break *always* breaks out of more than one scope, even if it's just the `if` block that says to break or not.  The only "odd" thing about it is how the `try-catch` is inside the loop, not outside of it, and that's not all that odd if you have a sequence of "tasks" and want to catch errors from them, but continue on with the rest.

Answer (score 4):

This is covered in 15.1 Throwing an exception:

> 2 When an exception is thrown, control is transferred to the nearest handler with a matching type (15.3);
>   “nearest” means the handler for which the compound-statement or ctor-initializer following the try keyword
>   was most recently entered by the thread of control and not yet exited.

Once control is transferred to the exception handler, it just continues from there. There is no mechanism to "remember" that the code was in the middle of a `break` and then somehow resume that after the exception is handled.

Comment: I'm not certain this is enough clarity. Consider that 6.6 section requires the jump statements to do as indicated and makes no mention of interruption to that flow. That is, I think the requirement you state and the jump reuirements are in conflict.

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y Would a reference to the standard to the effect of "destructors are called *before* the jump has occurred" answer this question?

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y: To be honest, having looked at 6.6 (especially the second paragraph), and I not sure I am seeing the ambiguity.

Comment: The problem is that the jump statements make no mention of _attempting_ to transfer flow, just that they do. In a very similar wording 15.1 there indicates a similar control transfer. Consider that `goto` uses the phrase __unconditionally transfers__, a stronger wording than exceptions, yet it is also caught by the exception.

Comment: Correct. The exception happens after the `break`, obviously, because it happens when leaving the scope, and that cannot happen before the `break`.

Answer (score 0):

In light of the specific wording in the stadnard, I'm going to say it is ambiguous. The text is insufficient to identify the intended flows these situations. It is quite possible the convention we have now is merely incidental due to how compilers are written.

Refer to my blog topic [How to catch a "return" statement](http://mortoray.com/2013/05/09/how-to-catch-a-return-statement/).